# MEAN: TypeError: ... is not a constructor

Tags: angularjs, constructor, authorization, mean-stack, typeerror

I'm very new to development and working my way through this MEAN tutorial: 
[MEAN Stack Front To Back [Part 3] - User Model & Register](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZeDy2QI3OE)

I've read a few questions on here but can't find a relevant answer.

Here is the primary error code:

```
Server started on port 3000
Database Error MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] 
on first connect
TypeError: User is not a constructor
at router.post (/Users/user/Desktop/Development/meanauthapp/routes/users.js:12:16)
```

Which is odd, because my mongod terminal states this:

```
2017-03-15T09:52:49.306-0700 I NETWORK  
[thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-03-15T09:52:54.514-0700 I NETWORK  
[thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49188 #1 (1 connection now open)
2017-03-15T09:52:54.515-0700 I NETWORK  
[conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:49188 conn1: 
{ application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, 
driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.4.1" }, 
os: { type: "Darwin", name: "Mac OS X", architecture: "x86_64", version: "15.6.0" } }
```

**/routes/users.js**

```
/*---------------Dependencies-------------*/
const express       = require('express');
const router            = express.Router();
const User              = require('../config/database');
const passport      = require('passport')
const jwt                   = require('jsonwebtoken'); 
/*----------------------------------------*/


/*---------------Register-----------------*/
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
    let newUser = new User({
        name:       req.body.name,
        email:      req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
        if(err) {
            res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed to register user'});
        } else {
            res.json({success: true, msg: 'User Registered'})
        }
    });
});
/*----------------------------------------*/


/*---------------Authenticate---------------*/
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('AUTHENTICATE')
});
/*----------------------------------------*/


/*-----------------Profile------------------*/
router.get('/profile', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('PROFILE')
});
/*----------------------------------------*/


module.exports = router;
```

The line with error is : let newUser = new User({

**/config/database.js**

```
 module.exports = {     database: "mongodb://localhost:27017/famjam",
 secret     : "yoursecret"  }
```

**/models/users.js**

```
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt        = require('bcryptjs');
const config        = require('../models/database');


/*User Scheme*/

const UserScheme = mongoose.Scheme({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserScheme);

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback) {
    User.findById(id, callback);
} 


module.exports.getUserbyUsername = function(username, callback) {
    const query = {username: username}
    User.findOne(query, callback);
} 


module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if(err) throw err; 
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        })
    });
}
```

**app.js**

```
/*---------------Dependencies-------------*/
const express       = require('express');
const path              = require('path');
const bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
const cors              = require('cors');
const passport      = require('passport');
const mongoose      = require('mongoose');
const users             = require('./routes/users') 
const config            = require('./config/database')
/*----------------------------------------*/


/*---------------Database-------------*/
mongoose.connect(config.database);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('connected to database ' +config.database)
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Database Error '+err)
});
/*----------------------------------------*/


/*------------------App-------------------*/
const app = express();

// Port Number
const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port '+port)
});

//CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());

// Body Parser Middelware
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/users', users)
/*----------------------------------------*/


/*---------------Index Route--------------*/
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Invalid Endpoint')
});


app.get('/myaccount', (req,res) =>{
    res.render('myaccount')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `req.body` is an `object` having `name, email, username` and `password` set, you should be able to create a new User simply doing:

```
let newUser = new User(req.body);
```

You get this error since you are passing to the constructor an object having 4 different attributes, while it expect to receive a request body.